# Java's Switch statement, adding case values together?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have been working hard to find a solution, but no dice yet. I am stuck trying to find a way to total of the values of the cases in a switch statement together. I will provide the homework question and my progress. Which will include the class and classTest. Thanks for any suggestions.

THE Homework ?

A large company pays its salespeople on a commission basis. The salespeople receive $200 per week plus 9% of their gross sales for that week. For example, a salesperson who sells $5000 worth of merchandise in a week receives $200 plus 9% of $5000, or a total of $650. You’ve been supplied with a list of the items sold by each salesperson. The values of these items are as follows:
Item Value
1 239.99
2 129.75
3 99.95
4 350.89

Develop a Java application that inputs one salesperson’s items sold for last week and calculates and displays that salesperson’s earnings. There’s no limit to the number of items that can be sold.

**************MY ISSUE:**************************************

**THE ISSUE ARISES WHEN I ATTEMPT TO ENTER MORE THAN ONE ITEM. THE PROGRAM WORKS WHEN I DO ONLY A SINGLE ITEM. HOWEVER, WHEN I DO MULTIPLES, THE PROGRAM NEVER TOTALS THE VALUES TOGETHER AND THE SALESPERSON EARNINGS ARE OFF**

*THE CLASS********************

```
public class SalesCommissionCalculator 
{
    private String item;
    private double value;

    public SalesCommissionCalculator()
    {
        setItem("");
        setValue(0.0);

    }

    public SalesCommissionCalculator(String i, double v)
    {
        setItem(i);
        setValue(v);

    }

    public void setItem(String i)
    {
        item = i;
    }

    public void setValue(double v)
    {   
        value = v;
    }


    public String getItem()
    {
        return item;
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Item"+item+"Value"+value);
    }

}
```

*********************THE ClassTest:*

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SalesCommissionCalculatorTest 
{
    public static void main(String args [])
    {

        int quantity;
        int item;
        double salary = 200.00;
        double commission = 0.09;
        double total= 0;
        String msg="";


        SalesCommissionCalculator item1 = new SalesCommissionCalculator("1", 239.99);
        SalesCommissionCalculator item2 = new SalesCommissionCalculator("2", 129.75);
        SalesCommissionCalculator item3 = new SalesCommissionCalculator("3", 99.95);
        SalesCommissionCalculator item4 = new SalesCommissionCalculator("4", 350.89);

        item=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item number 1, 2, 3 or 4. Enter -1 to quit."));

        while(item != -1)
        {
            switch(item)
            {
            case 1: quantity=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter quantity"));
                    total = (quantity*item1.getValue());
                    break;

            case 2: quantity=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter quantity"));
                    total= (quantity*item2.getValue());
                    break;

            case 3: quantity=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter quantity"));
                    total = (quantity*item3.getValue());
                    break;

            case 4: quantity=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter quantity"));
                    total = (quantity*item4.getValue());
                    break;

            default: 
                    System.out.println("Invalid Item Number");

            }

            item=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item number 1, 2, 3 or 4. Enter -1 to quit."));


        }

            msg = msg + String.format("Your Commission is $%.2f", (total*commission)+salary);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);

        }
    }
```

Comment: There are better ways to do this. Why not store the `SalesCommissionCalculator` items in an array? That way you have so much more functionality. You can output dynamically the items and their values, along with the corresponding input to access them. You wouldn't need the switch statement, you would just access that index of the array. Also, you should remove the setters from `SalesCommissionCalculator`. After it is created you shouldn't be changing properties.

Comment: programming tip,since salary and commission remain fixed you may declare them with keyword final as well bcz they never change for this particular problem,that may earn u more marks just put a comment to show what u are doing

Comment: and another tip if you are exprienced you can ask the user to enter all items at once maybe separated by a comma or something and then loop through the items and calculate for each item that would be less tiring than having to enter over and over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't accumulating the total in any of the cases. What you have right now (using case 1 as an example)

```
total = (quantity*item1.getValue());
```

just sets the total to be equal to `quantity*item1.getValue()`. What you probably wanted was

```
total += (quantity*item1.getValue());
```

instead. (and similarly for the other three cases)

Comment: Worked,

Man...had to be something simple. I can't thank you enough. I was becoming an ape, hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;
public class Sale {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

double value;
int item;
double earn= 0.0;
double total=0.0;

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Enter 1, 2, 3, 4 or \"-1 to quit\": ");
item = console.nextInt();

 while(item != -1)
 {
    switch(item)
    {
        case 1: 
            System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
            int quantity= console.nextInt();
            total = quantity * 239.99;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("Enter quantity:");
            quantity= console.nextInt();
            total = quantity * 129.75;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
            quantity= console.nextInt();
            total= quantity * 99.95;
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
            quantity= console.nextInt();
            total= quantity * 350.89;
            break;
        default: System.out.print("Invalid Item!");

    }
    if (total>=5000)
    {
        earn= total * 0.09;
    System.out.print("You have earned 9%, Your salary of the week : $"+earn);

    }

      else 
            System.out.println("Your salary of the week: $"+total);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Enter 1, 2, 3, 4 or \"-1 to quit\": ");
            item = console.nextInt();


 }
System.out.println("Thank you to visit our shop!");

}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain your answer instead of just dumping code? That way others can learn from it instead of just copying and pasting some code they may not understand.